# Passing method as parameter in Kotlin function issue

Tags: function, kotlin, parameters, parameter-passing

Which is cost effective process to pass method in kotlin function or call it using object?

Need help regarding cost issues.

Comment: I suppose it might depend on the runtime. I.e. JVM (which), KotlinJS, Native. Probably easiest to just write a simple benchmark test and run it on your target platform.

Comment: Can you show what you mean with some code? Your sentence is very unclear. Either way, I highly doubt it matters. Be careful not to prematurely optimise.

Comment: What sort of ‘cost’ are you referring to? CPU load, memory usage, code size, readability, testability, development time, maintenance costs…? I'd guess that readability and maintainability will be more important than any trivial variations in run time — though, as Sweeper says, it would be very helpful to see some code examples of what you're proposing. (If you write a benchmark, use a proper microbenchmarking framework, else you'd more likely to be testing the JVM warm-up, cache performance, or other irrelevances.)